# Create Report and charts with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, charts

i want to create reports for my asp.net website  for my sql server DB

and i am using c# and i want each report contains a chart and a table of data for that chart and be printable and saved as pdf.

i also want to know how to draw a chart like that

[image: chart]

from this query :

```
SELECT   
     SUM(CASE when ROUND( cast(DATEDIFF(day, BirthDateG,GETDATE())as real)/365.25,0) between 0 and 6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Group 1],
     SUM(CASE when ROUND( cast(DATEDIFF(day, BirthDateG,GETDATE())as real)/365.25,0) between 7 and 18  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Group 2],
     SUM(CASE when ROUND( cast(DATEDIFF(day, BirthDateG,GETDATE())as real)/365.25,0) between 19 and 25  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Group 3]

FROM Demographic 
group by Gender
```

Comment: it should be possible with rdlc report

Comment: so how to customize a report like what i mentioned in the question ?